# Is there a way to inline a bitmap canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap

I'm programming an online REPL for JavaScript much like those for Python. It has a characteristic that some outputs can be images, not only text. For example, a command could return a plotted graph. Those images are pre-rendered and represented internally as pixel arrays.

My doubt is how do I display that info on the screen. Should I encode my pixels to base64, returning an inlined `<img/>`? Or is there a way to inline pixel data for a canvas (which would be presumably faster)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: you have a pixel array coming from a different source than canvas and you want that data plotted onto a canvas?

To manually first encode this pixel array into PNG or JPEG and then to Base-64 would be a relatively slow process in JavaScript.

Instead you can return a typed array from your function and use a `Uint32Array` view on it for then to copy its data in a loop onto an array from the canvas using `createImageData` on the context object.

As with all bitmaps your function would necessary return width and height as well so your function should optimally return an object with reference to the array unless the dimension is always known in advance.

For example:

```
/// some function returning a bitmap/pixel array
function getSomeImageData() {

    ...
    return {
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitmap: myTypedArray
    }
}
```

Then in the copy process:

```
/// get the result from the function
var o = getSomeImageData();

/// create an empty bitmap
var img = context.createImageData(o.width, o.height);

/// create unsigned 32-bit views for the typed arrays
var dst = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
var src = new Uint32Array(o.bitmap);

/// copy using 32-bits integers
var i = src.length;
while(i--) dst[i] = src[i];

/// put image onto the canvas
context.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
```

(disclaimer: written inline, not tested)